# Blackberry and Windows phone 7 publishing of trivial app

Tags: windows-phone-7, blackberry

We have a mobile version of our web site which works well on all mobile screen resolutions and sizes. Now, we would like to build a very simple app for Blackberry and Windows Phone 7. The app would be trivial - after you click on its icon, it opens a web browser and send you to our mobile web site. Just like a Windows OS shortcut that you place on your desktop.

Can you tell me if Blackberry and Windows Phone 7 policies allow such app be published? For example, Apple rejected us.

Comment: Anyone has clue on Blackberry market?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't speak for Blackberry, but `Requirement 2.10` from the [WP7 Application Certification Requirements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh184841%28v=VS.92%29.aspx):

> Your application must have distinct,
>   substantial and legitimate content and
>        purpose other than merely launching a webpage.

So the answer seems to be no on the WP7 marketplace. Is there a reason you want to create an app like that anyway? On WP7, users can pin a tile to their home screen that will launch the website they've pinned. You could simply encourage users to do that on their WP7 and you'll get the same effect (except your site won't appear in the app list).

Comment: Thanks. I know I could do that. It's just that such app looks "more serious". What do you think if I add 2 buttons: one for the shortcut feature and the other something like email form or similar?

Comment: I can't really say as I only have access to the same guidelines as you. I guess it depends on how `substantial` is defined, but I imagine only the test team can give an answer on that (or someone who's tried submitting a similar app).

Answer (score 1):

Seems this is okay for BlackBerry.  See section 4.b of the [App World FAQ](http://us.blackberry.com/developers/appworld/faq.jsp).

Comment: Thanks you were right. No what should I do as both you and @keyboardP gave me the right answers?

Answer (score 0):

Very strange. Our company has placed a similar application on Android Market and the Appstore and they have been resolved and now they available at stores. Also, I had a similar application for Windovs Phone, and it was also allowed.

P.S. Our application is not just a browser window, it has custom control panel in bottom. Also it has the communication protocol with the site - such a sending pictures from camera and phone and access to phone contacts.

Comment: That is why it was approved by Apple :). We only need a shortcut functionality.

Comment: Maybe wep-application can help you? http://www.luscarpa.com/development/make-your-website-an-iphone-web-application/

Comment: As I see this is a web site that look like iPhone app? We have that already. :)